# How to smoothly change (shift) polygon's boarder in Cartesian coordinate system?

Tags: algorithms, polygons

My task is to smoothly change (shift) polygon's boarder in Cartesian coordinate system but i can't find such algorithm. I have found examples of what i want in graphic editors but can't find the algorithm name.

What is the name of the algorithm that smoothly changes the polygon boundary in this image?

[image]

Comment: That question is unclear to me. The image you provided is not a polygon. If I try to adapt your description and the image to the context of polygons, I'm still not sure what it is you want to do. The boundary (border) of a polygon is composed of vertices and line segments. Displacing one vertex or segment is not too difficult, although it still depends on what representation of the polygon you have. The potentially "difficult" part, is to know what parts of the polygon you want to preserve. I don't think there's a specific algorithm/operation for the transformation you want.

Comment: Actually, maybe what you want is an extrusion?

Comment: @N.Bach It is a polygon with a lot of vertices. Maybe this is extrusion not sure. Thx for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curves bordering your blue region look like (cubic) Bézier curves. Each Bézier curve is defined by four points. Two of these points are its end-points, which are shown as black squares in your picture. The other two points are interior "control points", which are shown as white squares in your picture.

Where two Bézier curves meet, you get a black point (which is the common end-point of the two Bézier curves), and two white points, one from each curve. These three points are often collinear, which causes the two curves to meet smoothly.

Just look up "editing of Bézier curves".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like Bézier Curves but I am still not sure:

[Link 1](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#polybezier)

[Link 2](http://www.antigrain.com/research/bezier_interpolation/)